# an access problem:OutputTo not work in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

i Have used this code in access 2010 for genrating pdf file
 DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report2", ".pdf", "C:\Graph_report2.pdf", True

it is working fine in access 2010 but when i open my access database in access 2007 it gives Runtime error 2501 that 'The OutputTo action was cancelled' and not pdf file is open.

Big problem !what i do? Plz Help

Comment: You have to make sure that the pdf plugin is installed for 2007.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=f1fc413c-6d89-4f15-991b-63b07ba5f2e5&displaylang=en

Comment: @ZippyV: that's the actual answer, and you should post it as such instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report2", ".pdf", "C:\Graph_report2.pdf", True
```

should be:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report2", acFormatPDF, "C:\Graph_report2.pdf", True
```

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Can I add that apart that one needs to install an add in for PDF output and then start Access 2007, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9943

If one tries to save the file in a directory that does not exist, this error will also pop up.

Here is a function for PDF output:

```
    Function PrintToPDF(SrcReport As String, DestPath As String, DestFile As String, ShowPdf As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo PrintToPDF_Err

    'ScrReport = The report Name to output as PDF
    'DestPath = Destination path for PDF file e.g. C:/DatabaseReports/Financial/
    'DestFile = File name for the PDF file being created, but without the file extension, one can add date to it
    'Showpdf = launch pdf viwer and display this PDF output

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, SrcReport, "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", DestPath & DestFile & ".pdf", ShowPdf, "", 0, acExportQualityPrint

  PrintToPDF_Exit:
    Exit Function

  PrintToPDF_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume PrintToPDF_Exit


   End Function
```